# std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator’ has no member named ‘c_str’

Tags: c++

i have problem with this. It says this:

```
‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator’ has no member named ‘c_str’
```

Could you help me, please ?

```
for ( ObjectMgr::WayContainer::const_iterator itr = Ways.begin(); itr != Ways.end(); ++itr )
{

char *cstr = new char[itr.length() + 1];
strcpy(cstr, itr.c_str());

if ( !stricmp(cstr, wayss) )
{
return;
}

delete [] cstr;
}
```

Comment: I see no reason why you have to copy out the string instead of passing `itr->c_str()` to the comparison function directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of

```
itr.c_str()
```

write

```
itr->c_str()
```

Because `c_str` is a member not of the iterator but of the `std::string` it refers to. In the same vein, replace `itr.length()` with `itr->length()`.